# Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at blob

Tags: content-security-policy

Blob images aren't showing via JavaScript because of the Content Security Policy in Waterfox 56:

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a
>   resource at blob:http://localhost/1e511fde-fb52-41fc-b7db-6b8b6cf64171
>   (“img-src http://localhost data:”).

My image CSP:

```
img-src \'self\' data:;
```

Self-answered, see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `blob:` resolves the issue, only use a space for the array delimiter (and semi-colons for the key/value pair delimiters):

Before:

```
img-src \'self\' data:;
```

After:

```
img-src \'self\' blob: data:;
```

Comment: where to add it in Tomcat?